# Can't change font on paragraph (html css)

Tags: html, css, fonts

i have the strangest problem. I can't seem to change the font in a paragraph, no matter how much i manipulate the styles in chrome dev tools.
i unchecked all the font lines, and it still shows a strange font that i have used in a heading. i added the font that i want (arial) as inline element style, and pretty much anywhere else, and still strange font.
how can i find out where's the problem. i have to say that i did use a style sheet that someone else wrote. but still, how can i know what's the matter if i uncheck all the lines in chrome and no results....
and another thing, in a different section of the page there's no problem displaying arial font.

it is driving me crazy...

the code is scattered. the relevant paragraph is:

```
 <div id="last">
 <div id="info">
```

`<a href="http://xxxxxx.com"><img src="images/logo.png"  /></a>`

```
<p style="margin-top:15px; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
 xxxxx is an initiative of <a href="http://xxxxx.com">xxxxxx.com</a>, an organization committed to teaching and inspiring people of all ages about Judaism and Israel.<br /> For more information, questions or inquiries, please email <a href="xxxxxxxxxx">xxxxxx.com</a> </p>
 </div>
```

tried changing the font of the body and #last #info and also the inline style as you can see.

Comment: Please show some codes over here. And the other thing you can do is try adding `!important` to the font-family property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
font: Arial;
```

to

```
font-family: Arial;
```

Comment: the 'font' property is a shorthand declaration. For example,
font: 15px, Arial; 
would work, but to specify multiple fonts, you need to declare a font-family.

Comment: @zethus yep, I went with font-family because he said that he is using a stylesheet that he didn't create and he wasn't specifying the height of the font when he was trying to change the font-family, so I made the assumption that he wanted to inherit the default font-size.